How to know if my node module is being installed in dev mode or in dependency mode
There are two different situations where you run npm install:

You run npm install in your project's root directory
Someone added your module as a dependency of their own project and they run npm install

npm runs the postinstall script you specified in your package.json.
npm is aware of this difference, that's why it installs your devDependencies in the first situation and skip them in the second situation.
I need to know about this in my postinstall script, in order to run different steps for folks working directly on my module's code, rather than using my module as a dependency. Something like:
if (DEPENDENCY_MODE) {
    // someone added me to their dependencies
    // download a Minimal version of some binary
} else {
    // I'm being developed by my maintainer
    // download a Verbose version of some binary
}

Is there any Globals / Env variables that I can check to get this details?

Note that if you just need this to perform additional steps "when devs work directly on the code", that already has an established pattern: tell them to run a dedicated "for devs only" npm script as part of setting up their workspace, just like everyone else.

The only environment variable exposed by running an npm script out-of-the-box is npm_lifecycle_event which simply says which current lifecycle event is running.

I found a few solutions to distinguish between these two cases:
Solution 1
Compare npm_config_local_prefix and npm_package_json environment variables.
npm_config_local_prefix contains the path the command is running at (same  as process.env.INIT_CWD). For example C:\app.
npm_package_json contains the path to the package.json file of the package being installed at the moment. For example C:\app\package.json OR C:\app\node_modules\my-package\package.json.
if (process.env.npm_config_local_prefix === process.env.npm_package_json.slice(0, -13)) {
    // this is the main project
} else {
    // this is a dependency of another package
}

Solution 2
Check for the node_modules directory, can be inaccurate in some cases.
const fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync('../node_modules')) {
    // this is a dependency of another package
} else {
    // this is the main project
}


There isn't a specific environment variable that directly tells you whether the installation is for a project's dependencies or devDependencies. However, you can infer this information by checking the existence of the node_modules directory in the parent directory of your package. If the node_modules directory exists, then your package is being installed as a dependency. If it doesn't exist, then your package is being installed for development purposes.

Note that this isn't strictly speaking true if someone's master directory for working on git projects has a package.json for "universal" packages they want to be able to run using npx. If the project is a dependency, there is a node_modules in the parent dir, but the reverse is not true: you can't rely on the fact that if there is a node_modules, the code must therefor have been installed as dependency.

Based on the additional details from your comments, there isn't really any need for a postinstall script here: you explicitly don't want to run this after every npm install, you only want to run this when devs bootstrap your project so they can work on it, which already has an established solution: have a normal npm script that you tell devs to run as part of the documentation for project setup.
Loads of projects will have two sections in their README.md for this purpose, with one section that tells normal users how to install the code as a dependency (typically being the trivial npm install packagename and/or yarn install packagename) and then a separate set of instructions for devs, typically along the lines of "clone the project, cd into the dir, run npm install, then run a one-time npm run some-dev-only-script. Then run npm test to verify that everything's working as expected".
So in  your case, specifically, since you say the script should download dev-only files, you probably want a script called download-dev-data or the like that does what the script name implies it will do.
And then if you also need to run that step during CI, just update your CI script (gh actions, circle ci, travis, whatever you're using) to include that run command before running npm test.

Original answer based on the original post text that made no mention of why you needed this:
Nodejs's own documentation literally covers your question, with code, in the first section:
"Node.js assumes it's always running in a development environment. You can signal Node.js that you are running in production by setting the NODE_ENV=production environment variable."
As for how to check which mode you're in, in your code:
"You can use conditional statements to execute code in different environments:"
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // ...
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // ...
}

if (['production', 'staging'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
  // ...
}

Definitely give the Nodejs docs a read-through, they tend to already cover any question you might have.
(And note that there is no such thing as "dependency mode", it's called "development mode")

I don't think that NODE_ENV has anything to do with the fact that my module is being installed as a dependency or not, I can use this environment variable if and only if I could force all the people that are installing my package to use the production flag npm install --production so they can signal me about it!

Note that your module should not need to care which mode it's being installed in: if it gets installed, then its own regular dependencies list should include everything it needs. It should never need anything from its devDependencies when installed as a module in another project, because those dependencies are only for its own development (this is why modules that have build steps expose the build result as main entry point, not the unbuilt source file)

In my postinstall script I get process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined when my users don't specify --production (which is the normal behavior when people install any package)

Right, but why does your module need to know which mode it's even in? It just needs to know whether it's getting installed or not. If it is, all it should need in order to work as intended are its own dependencies (but not devDependencies, because it's being used as a module, people aren't working on your module itself). It feels like your question is missing very important details that explain your actual use-case here: please edit your post to include those.

You're right about devDependencies, but I need the same logic in my postinstall. (if package.json had a devPostinstall that would be awesome!)

My use case is downloading a binary file in the postinstall step for the module's developers and skip that for the module's users.

Please put that in your post, don't just tell "me" in a comment, tell everyone as part of your question (since you're offering a bounty). If someone's working on the module own code, then you have other ways to ensure that they have the data they need to work on the code, e.g. a one time npm run bootstrap call. Your post needs to make it clear that's the actual problem you're trying to solve: you posted an XY problem =)

I personally wouldn't use the postinstall script to create executables meant for consumers of your published package, but instead use a pre-publish script to download the executable before building and publishing to npm. The scripts documentation states:

If you need to perform operations on your package before it is used, in a way that is not dependent on the operating system or architecture of the target system, use a prepublish script. This includes tasks such as:

Compiling CoffeeScript source code into JavaScript.
Creating minified versions of JavaScript source code.
Fetching remote resources that your package will use.


Also, as mentioned by others, it is normal to include a separate npm script for development purposes. It is also a good idea to create scripts for seprate workflows, i.e. development vs builds vs publish, etc.
In your particular case I would suggest using the prepack hook and the NODE_ENV environment variable to help distinguish which version of the executable to download. Your updated scripts might look like this:
"files": [
  "dist",
  "executable"
],
"scripts": {
  "prepack": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build",
  "prebuild": "tsx prebuild.ts",
  "build": "eslint src test && tsc",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development npm run build"
}

This way your publish workflow would run npm pack, and your maintainer workflow would run npm run dev. Inside of prebuild.ts you could then read from NODE_ENV to determine which executable to download.
I put together a PR with the changes suggested here if you were interested.

Thanks! This will publish the executable file to npm, right? Is it a standard approach to publish third party executables to registries while users can download directly from respective publishers?

This executable seems to be a dependency of your package right, i.e. your package is unusable without? If so you have to provide it somehow. Maybe you’re looking for the bin field of package.json as an alternative way to distribute? All depends on the API you want to expose to end users.
